# QueryAsync returning nothing for ID column (auto number column)

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms App with a SQLite database. I'm experiencing an issue when trying to retrieve values from an auto-incremented column using `QueryAsync`. The function looks like this:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<int, string>> GetDicIDsNames()
{
    List<IdName> idNamesList = await db.QueryAsync<IdName>("SELECT StudentID, Name FROM [Student]");
        
    Dictionary<int, string> dicIDsNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    foreach (IdName item in idNamesList)
    {
        dicIDsNames.Add(item.id, item.name);
    }
    return dicIDsNames;
}
```

The goal of the function is to return a Dictionary of Student IDs and Names. When I put a breakpoint in the code I was able to see that the first line of code populates the `idNamesList` with all the student names, but all of the IDs are 0 and I don't know why.

I have a Student class/table with a definition like this:

```
public class Student
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

There are additional fields but I'll leave them out since they are irrelevant to the question.
Here is a short class "IdName" I created for working with the return values:

```
public class IdName
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Another kind of odd thing is that when I query the database and return a full student object the StudentID property is returned/set properly. I could easily return every student in the table then loop through to extract the id and name fields from there but that would be quite inefficient.

Why would it be returning 0 or null values? Or if there is a way I can select the columns by index that would work too since I just need the first 2 columns from the table.

Comment: Does `IdName` have a `StudentID` property? What happens if you change `SELECT StudentID` to `SELECT StudentID as ID`?

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it turns out that my return data type of IdName has to have variables with the exact same names as the column names in my table. I thought the variables could be any name but I tried this out and it solved the issue

```
public class IdName
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks mjwills for helping me find the solution.